# How to remove text from the beginning of a string based on condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, data-cleaning

suppose i have the following text:

```
'Reuters - Life is beautiful.'
'agency.com - China\'s currency remains pegged to the dollar and the US currency\'s sharp falls in recent months have therefore made - Chinese export prices highly competitive.'
'AP - The number of days that beaches closed or posted warnings because of pollution rose sharply in 2003 due to more rainfall, increased monitoring and tougher -standards, an environmental group said on Thursday.'
'CNN - Warming water temperatures - in the central equatorial Pacific last month may indicate the start of a new El Nino.'
```

I want to remove all text only at the beginning of the text that's before a `"-"` and only if the `"-"` is followed by a whitespace.

I would like something like:

```
if line.startswith(code_to_match_my_condition):
      strip_matched_text_from_line
```

So the results would be:

```
'Life is beautiful.'
'China\'s currency remains pegged to the dollar and the US currency\'s sharp falls in recent months have therefore made - Chinese export prices highly competitive.'
'The number of days that beaches closed or posted warnings because of pollution rose sharply in 2003 due to more rainfall, increased monitoring and tougher -standards, an environmental group said on Thursday.'
'Warming water temperatures - in the central equatorial Pacific last month may indicate the start of a new El Nino.'
```

I actually don't know how to code this. I would appreciate any help on this.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use a regular expression, such as

```
^[^-]+-\s+
```

and replace this with an empty string, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/SmuB0a/1/).

---

In `Python` this could be:

```
import re

strings = ['Reuters - Life is beautiful.',
           'agency.com - China\'s currency remains pegged to the dollar and the US currency\'s sharp falls in recent months have therefore made - Chinese export prices highly competitive.',
           'AP - The number of days that beaches closed or posted warnings because of pollution rose sharply in 2003 due to more rainfall, increased monitoring and tougher -standards, an environmental group said on Thursday.',
           'CNN - Warming water temperatures - in the central equatorial Pacific last month may indicate the start of a new El Nino.']

rx = re.compile(r'^[^-]+-\s+')

strings = list(map(lambda string: rx.sub("", string), strings))
print(strings)
```

And yields

```
['Life is beautiful.', "China's currency remains pegged to the dollar and the US currency's sharp falls in recent months have therefore made - Chinese export prices highly competitive.", 'The number of days that beaches closed or posted warnings because of pollution rose sharply in 2003 due to more rainfall, increased monitoring and tougher -standards, an environmental group said on Thursday.', 'Warming water temperatures - in the central equatorial Pacific last month may indicate the start of a new El Nino.']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) But why it is not working in cases like: `AP -- asdasd` How could i make it work when there are two consecutives "-"? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simple, readable code to search and remove the block:

```
if " - " in line:
    index = line.find(" - ")
    line = line[index+3:]
```

Comment: Thank you!! but this would remove more than only the text in the beginning of the sentences. There are more "-" mixed inside the texts, and i don't want the text before those additional "-" to be affected

Comment: Yeah, fixed that

Comment: This will take into consideration all the "-" present in the texts, i just want to remove the text that's before the first "-" and only before the first "-"

Comment: Have you tried running it? Works exactly the way you have specified